# Algorithm to fill an array randomly without collision

Tags: arrays, algorithm, fill, random-access

Say I have an array of N integers set to the value '0', and I want to pick a random element of that array that has the value '0' and put it to value '1'

How do I do this efficiently ?

I came up with 2 solutions but they look quite ineficient

First solution

```
int array[N] //init to 0s
int n //number of 1s we want to add to the array
int i = 0
while i < n
    int a = random(0, N)
    if array[a] == 0
        array[a] = 1
        i++
    end if
end while
```

It would be extremely inefficient for large arrays because of the probability of collision

The second involves a list containing all the 0 positions remaining and we choose a random number between 0 and the number of 0 remaining to lookup the value in the list that correspond to the index in the array.
It's a lot more reliable than the first solution, since the number of operations is bounded, but still has a worst case scenario complexity of N² if we want to fill the array completely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second solution is actually a good start. I assume that it involves rebuilding the list of positions after every change, which makes it O(N²) if you want to fill the whole array. However, you don't need to rebuild the list every time. Since you want to fill the array anyway, you can just use a random order and choose the remaining positions accordingly.

As an example, take the following array (size 7 and not initially full of zeroes) : `[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]`

Once you have built the list of zeros positions, here `[0, 1, 3, 6]`, just shuffle it to get a random ordering. Then fill in the array in the order given by the positions.

For example, if the shuffle gives `[3, 1, 6, 0]`, then you can fill the array like so :

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]  <- initial configuration
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]  <- First, position 3
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]  <- Second, position 1
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]  <- etc.
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

If the array is initially filled with zeros, then it's even easier. Your initial list is the list of integers from 0 to N (size of the array). Shuffle it and apply the same process.

If you do not want to fill the whole array, you still need to build the whole list, but you can truncate it after shuffling it (which just means to stop filling the array after some point).

Of course, this solution requires that the array does not change between each step.

Comment: I think it is the most efficient way to do it, since I don't do operations on the resulting array that modifies it
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can fill array with `n` ones and `N-n` zeros and make random shuffling.

[Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) has linear complexity:

```
for i from N−1 downto 1 do
     j ← random integer such that 0 ≤ j ≤ i
     exchange a[j] and a[i]
```

Comment: The thing is I need the intermediate array states in an other process

Comment: You need array with 1 one, then with 2 ones and so on? Should they be in random places or monotone increasing random sequence is suitable?

Comment: "You need array with 1 one, then with 2 ones and so on?" Yes. The new ones that are added at each steps should be randomly selected amongst the remaining zeros

Comment: First option - 5,12, 6, 2.  Second - 2, 5, 6, 12. Is the second one suitable?

Comment: "First option - 5,12, 6, 2. Second - 2, 5, 6, 12. Is the second one suitable?" I have no idea what you're trying to say

Comment: Second approach - fill random places but in increasing order

Comment: UV'd - this is the correct way of doing this from a statistical perspective.